# tracking a sprite body position as it moves

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

This might sound quite straightforward. I want to keep track of a sprite body position only AFTER it has been moved by a mouseJoint so I can limit it's movement by comparing it's position (at any given time after mouseJoint is released) with a given position. Please help.

**UPDATED**

Here's what I did. I made a method that returns the sprite's position, which I called in the ccTouchesEnded method:

```
- (CGPoint)spritePositionRelease    {

for(b2Body *b = mouseJoint->GetBodyB(); b; b=b->GetNext())    {
    if (b->GetUserData() != NULL)
    {
        CCSprite *mySprite = (CCSprite*)b->GetUserData();
        if (mySprite.tag == 1) {
            mySprite.position = CGPointMake( b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO, b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO);
            spritePosition = mySprite.position;
            CCLOG(@"the sprite position is x:%0.2f , y:%0.2f", spritePosition.x, spritePosition.y);

            return spritePosition;
        }
    }
}
}
```

ccTouchesEnded:

```
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

if (mouseJoint)
{
    [self spritePositionRelease];
    world->DestroyJoint(mouseJoint);
    mouseJoint = NULL;
}
}
```

In the tick method I added the following code:

```
        for(b2Body *b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b=b->GetNext())    {
        if (b->GetUserData() != NULL)
        {
            CCSprite *mySprite = (CCSprite*)b->GetUserData();
            if (mySprite.tag == 1) {
                mySprite.position = CGPointMake( b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO, b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO);
                CGPoint spriteCurrentPosition = mySprite.position;

                if ( spritePosition.x != spriteCurrentPosition.x && 
                     spritePosition.y == spriteCurrentPosition.y) {
                    CCLOG(@"the sprite limit for y is y:%0.2f has been reached",  spriteCurrentPosition.y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I initialized the spritePosition in the HelloWorldLayer.h class. I know I've done something wrong. I don't think the spritePosition I am accessing in the tick method has the same value as the spritePosition in the ccTouchesEnded method, hence the condition in the tick method never gets satisfied. I am not sure how to get this corrected. Please help

Comment: What have you tried so far? Seems to me that you could just get the position of the body with GetPosition() any time you like.

Comment: @iforce2d: I just updated the question with what i've done. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ccpdistance(X2 , X1);` to find the distance between two points. And from that distance you can limit the range that sprite can move.